SQL - trying to eliminate a loop
In Oracle...
The end result of a query needs to return the top X areas which have the highest concentrations of accounts, where the ‘highest concentration’ means the number of accounts within a 100 mile radius.
I start with a query against a table. I have to start with a query since the end-user will be adding criteria.  Each query comes back with the account key and the longitude/latitude of the account.
So the input of this process will be something like
Select account_key, longitude, latitude from accounts
Where 
Condition1 = 'Y' and Condition2 = 'N';  -- as an example

This might return 2000 rows.  Out of those 2000 rows, there will be clusters of high account areas.  I need to identify those areas.  One way of doing this is to loop through all 2000 rows, and determine the count of other accounts within the 100 mile radius. I would then choose my top entries, eliminating overlapping radius.
Loop….
 Select count(account_key) from accounts
 Where 
 Calc_distance(longitude, latitude) < 100 and
 Condition1 = 'Y' and Condition2 = 'N';  -- as an example

  Insert into output_table (this_account_key, this_count);
End loop

The problem is that this is definitely NOT performant.
Is there a way to rewrite this operation so that I don’t have to loop?

please tag your database system see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

INSERT INTO table SELECT ... ?

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for a minimal example of the problem (i.e. 20 rows of data, not 2000); the CREATE FUNCTION statement for your calc_distance function; an English (not code) explanation of how the logic should be applied to that sample data; and the expected output for your sample data. At the moment, your question is too abstract so it is very difficult for people without your domain knowledge to understand what the problem is and you need a concrete example with a detailed explanation.

You're asking for a high degree of machine intelligence. Humans can easily see patterns and find the center of groupings because groupings are easy for us to pick out. Computers have a much harder time doing this. Starting with each of your values and looping doesn't work, as you may have a grouping around a center that is not itself represented.  Perhaps you'd need to try every possible lat/long within the min/max of your set of data, but that would be an enormous amount of work. I'm sure there are advanced methods out there, but I doubt any of them will perform well. This is what MPP is for.

As for speeding up a predicate like Calc_distance(longitudeA, latitudeA, longitudeA, longitudeB) < 100, you could use the property of hypotenuses always being longer than the sides of a triangle and add a range predicate on top (in addition to) the function: AND latitudeA BETWEEN latitudeB - 100 AND latitudeB + 100 AND longitudeA BETWEEN longitudeB - 100 AND longitudeB + 100, which if lat/long are indexed can do a range scan and only execute the function for rows that have a possibility of being within range. The function would still be needed to filter this down further, but called less.

Oracle supports some data mining packages (but they are probably additional cost options so check what your license allows before you try using them) and they can perform clustering. There is an example of using K-Means clustering on this 3rd-party site: https://dzone.com/articles/solving-the-clustering-problem-with-oracle-data-mi
